# Google Eclipse plugin warning for bad server classpath

Tags: java, gwt, eclipse-indigo, google-eclipse-plugin

I have installed the Google-Eclipse plugin to create a GWT/GAE app. I added the `joda-time-2.1.jar` for handling dates and times on the server-side. I did this by adding the JAR to a `lib/` directory in my project, and then adding the JAR to the project buildpath.

As soon as I did this I see a *Warning* spring up inside the Eclipse `Problems` view:

> The following classpath entry '/home/myuser/workbench/eclipse/workspace/myapp/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar' will not be available on the server's classpath.

I haven't gotten this far yet but was planning on packaging this JAR under the `WEB-INF/lib` directory inside the app WAR, which *should* make it available to the server classpath.

Have I configured something incorrectly here? If so, what? And if not, how do I silence/get rid of this warning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a bad question please tell me why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Have I configured something incorrectly here?

No.

> If so, what? And if not, how do I silence/get rid of this warning?

Move the JAR to `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - so do I need to manually ad JARs to my project buildpath **AND** place them in `WEB-INF/lib`, or just place them in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: And what about test dependencies?!? I shouldn't have to place `junit` into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory in order to *not* have a compiler warning...